# array to generate form

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I am trying to use an array to output a form with the following function:

```
public function createArrayForm($table, $do, $formDesc = '', $id, $array, $markFields = false) {
    if (!isset($table) && !isset($do)) {
        self::show_error('One or more parameters are missing in ' . __FUNCTION__);
    } elseif ($table == 'update' && !isset($id)) {
        self::show_error('For this form to be built, and ID must be set. Missing parameter `ID` in ' . __FUNCTION__);
    }
    if (is_array($array) && $do == 'insert') {
        $out .= '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?id=' . $id . '&table=' . $table . '" method="post" class="form-horizontal" ' . $formAppend . '>';
        $out .= '<div class="form-desc">' . $formDesc . '</div>';
        $out .= $markFields ? '<h3>Input Fields</h3>' : '';
        foreach ($array as $type => $fieldname) {
            if ($type == 'input') {
                $out .= generateInputField($fieldname);
            }
        }
        $out .= $markFields ? '<h3>Content Fields</h3>' : '';
        foreach ($array as $type => $fieldname) {
            if ($type == 'textarea') {
                $out .= generateTextarea($fieldname, $cke);
            }
        }
        $out .= $markFields ? '<h3>Images Fields</h3>' : '';
        foreach ($array as $type => $fieldname) {
            if ($type == 'image') {
                $out .= generateImgField($fieldname);
            }
        }
        $out .= form_hidden('user_data', '1');
        $out .= form_hidden('id', self::generateID());
        $out .= form_close();
        return $out;
    }
```

And call:

```
$arr = array("textarea"=>"project_name", "input"=>"created", "input"=>"last_modified", "input"=>"published");
echo $automate->createArrayForm('projects', 'insert', 'Some form desc', '123', $arr, true);
```

**But it only outputs:**

[image]

**When it should look something like this:**

[image]

Only one of each, for example input, is returned. Rather than all instances of it. So `"input"=>"created", "input"=>"last_modified", "input"=>"published"` should make three inputs, but it only returns one.

Comment: You need to clarify what your problem is.. What's wrong with your output?

Comment: only one of each for example input is returned

Comment: I am also confused by you're question. Can you try explaining what you think code should do instead of making us read it and assume for ourselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-using array keys. So

```
$arr = array("textarea"=>"project_name", "input"=>"created", "input"=>"last_modified", "input"=>"published");
```

will end up looking like this:

```
$arr = array("textarea"=>"project_name", "input"=>"published");
```

Instead, modify your code to something like this:

```
$arr = array("textarea"=>array("project_name"), "input"=>array("created", "last_modified", "published"));
```

Then take those individual arrays, and iterate through them.

```
foreach ($array['input'] as $fieldname) { // etc and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, you cannot have arrays that share keys.

You'll be best creating a simple array, and creating sub-entries, so that you maintain order, but can have more than one input/textarea.

Like so:

```
$arr = array(
    array('type' => 'textarea', 'name' => 'project_name'),
    array('type' => 'input', 'name' => 'created'),
    array('type' => 'input', 'name' => 'published'),
    array('type' => 'input', 'name' => 'last_modified')
)
```

This would also allow you to add more parameters than type/name.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you use the same key for everything in the array.
A possibility would be to exchange values and keys

```
$arr = array("textarea"=>"project_name", "input"=>"created", "input"=>"last_modified", "input"=>"published");

[...]
foreach ($array as $fieldname => $type) {
    if ($type == 'textarea') {
        $out .= generateTextarea($fieldname, $cke);
    }
}
[...]
```